# execv with user input

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

I am writing a little programm in x86er assembly intel syntax. It should ask the user for input like "ls" and execute this command through "/bin/sh -c ". But it didn't work.. 
The problem is the adress of "ls". I can't insert the adress of the input in the argument array. Here some output of gdb:

```
gdb$ x/s 0x8049115
0x8049115:  "\034\221\004\bDDDls\n"
```

as you can see.. I am copying the string not the adress of the string. How can I fix the problem? :)

Here is my code:

```
section .bss
buffer: resb 128

section .data
msg: db "Your Input here: "
len: equ $-msg
exec: db "/bin/sh#-c#AAAABBBBCCCCDDDD"

section .text
global _start

_start:

  mov eax, 4
  mov ebx, 1
  mov ecx, msg
  mov edx, len
  int 0x80

  mov eax, 3
  mov ebx, 0
  mov ecx, buffer
  int 0x80

  xor eax, eax
  mov byte [exec + 7], al
  mov byte [exec + 10], al
  mov long [exec + 12], exec
  lea ebx, [exec + 8]
  mov long [exec + 16], ebx
  lea ebx, [buffer]
  mov long [exec + 20], ebx
  mov long [exec + 24], eax
  mov byte al, 0x0b
  mov ebx, exec
  lea ecx, [exec + 12]
  lea edx, [exec + 24]
  int 0x80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few problems there:

1. You only reserve 27 bytes at `exec` but you need 28 so you overwrite the start of `buffer`.  What you are seeing in `gdb` is part your `exec` block followed by the `buffer`. Notice you have 3 `D` placeholders left, but you will write 4 more bytes. This is the main issue.
2. You pass the message length into the `read` syscall. Not a terrible problem but limits input to 17 bytes while you have space for 128.
3. The `read` system call returns the line feed, but doesn't null terminate the string. Depending on memory layout, you might get lucky with a following zero byte and the line feed is ignored by the shell. For safety you should replace the `\n` with a 0 yourself.

Comment: Hello Thx for your advice. But why do I need 28 bytes? I mean pointer are 4 bytes big. I need 4 arguments right? Can you explain this? :)

Comment: `mov long [exec + 24], eax` will write into bytes at offsets 24 through 27, but 27 is already part of `buffer`. Note that offsets start from 0. Count them.